# Identifying which websites are using ReCAPTCHA v1 in order to upgrade

Tags: recaptcha, captcha, google-developer-tools

Google is currently sending out a mass email that looks like this:

> Dear Webmaster,
>
> You are receiving this email because you are registered as a website administrator using reCAPTCHA, and your website is still using reCAPTCHA v1, which will be turned off on March 31, 2018.
>
> We announced the reCAPTCHA v1 deprecation in May 2016. Starting in November 2017, a small percentage of reCAPTCHA v1 traffic will begin to show a notice informing users that the old API will soon be retired. Any calls to the v1 API will not work after March 31, 2018.
>
> To ensure continued functionality, you’ll need to update your website to a current version of reCAPTCHA. You can learn more about reCAPTCHA v2, Invisible reCAPTCHA and reCAPTCHA Android API in our Developer’s Guide. The new APIs are simple to implement and will streamline the captcha experience for your users. If you need help, you can engage in the reCAPTCHA Google Developer Group or post to Stack Overflow with the ‘recaptcha’ tag.
>
> We hope that your upgrade will be seamless, and we’re confident you’ll be happy with the results.
>
> Thank you,
>
> reCAPTCHA Support

For those of who have built dozens (or hundreds) of sites with ReCAPTCHA over the years, is there a simple way to identify which websites are using version 1?

This question has also been asked in the Google Developers ReCAPTCHA group (by someone else) and I will monitor answers there and post them here if they are relevant: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/KRzmHivCtjM

Comment: Haha...came here wondering the exact same thing. Thank you so much Google for letting us know which page(s) are still sending you requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a look at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list. However for me all of the sites have `V2` as `Site Type` while I got the same email as you. While checking some of the sites I noticed they were actually using reCAPTCHA v1.

Comment: Thanks, that's the sort of dashboard I was hoping for listing all my api keys. Unfortunately, I am in the same situation as you: all my sites show v2 even though I got the email.

Comment: I have only one site using reCaptcha, and I know it is still using v1, yet that Google reCaptcha dashboard shows it as using V2, so, yes, Google is not visibly flagging v1 sites, but insteading showing them as V2.

Comment: While going to the admin console may show you the sites you have setup... it still just says (for me) "*Your site is currently using reCAPTCHA v1...*". Really wish it at least gave a URL from whence they claim this is happening from. I've scoured the code, and cannot find v1 anywhere :/

Answer (score -1):

One method: Browse each site and look at the very recaptcha itself:

v1 == punch in letters to complete the captcha.

v2 == select images to complete the captcha.

Could be tedious, yes, but should do the job.